# Django RestFramework Elastic Search: Timeline API

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, django-views

[image: screenshot of timeline]

I'm using django restframework  along with elastic search to develop a backend application for a mobile app. I need to develop a timeline API that will load a timeline of posts from other users the user is following. Along with  other related poststhat the people they're following  may comment.

What is the best implementation method for this problem?

Comment: Filter all docs and aggs with some field,finally sort with time.

Comment: The timeline API will have various kinds of documents, i.e one can be event, the other can be a post or comment under the event. All documents will be sorted by time. Is there such a way for that kind of implementation? 
If so could you provide an example.

Comment: POST index1,index2,index3/_search    {do sort}  #You might want to sort the fields the same

Comment: can you provide a code example?

Comment: @Johnny A solution I thought of is creating a "post" model that would have various foriegn fields to its contents. Which I think would be optimum for search performance and much easier to format on the front end but would result in a another model that will require maintenance

Comment: It's too much work, and it's not very efficient,it is clearer to use es query directly.

Comment: @Johnny I see. Could you give a snipped example of multiple documents in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
@some_vf
def someview(req, **kw):
    query = {
        "_source": ["field1", "field2", "field3"],
        "query": {
            "must": [
                {"term": {"username": "zhangsan"}}
            ],
            "should": [
                {"term": {"userid": 1}},
                {"term": {"followed": "something"}}  # other filter with zhangsan
            ]
        },
        "sort": [{"timestamp": {"order": "asc"}}],
        "size": size,
        "from": from_
    }
    es = Elasticsearch()
    data = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, ["user_docs_index", "related_posts_index", "followed_some_index"], "_doc")
    # or do your serializers
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: a few questions,

I'm not sure but I would need a custom get_queryset for the related index to prevent a user from seeing data that they should not have access to.

field names are the same in some indexes because they share an abstract base model class. How would I distinguage between the them?

Comment: @Fendz242 Are you saying that the same field may have different access rights?

Comment: No, I'm saying various documents have access rights. Example the timeline should only return users that are being followed. Same for Events. But by default all would be returned. I need to filter the queryset of the various documents.

Comment: No, I'm saying various documents have access rights. Example the timeline should only return users that are being followed. Same for Events. But by default all would be returned. I need to filter the queryset of the various documents.

Comment: @Fendz242  the query eg is that do it, you can use query to return users data that are being followed, and use `_source` key to return fields you need